# Clipboard does not exist in the current content

Tags: c#

I want to use `Clipboard.GetText()` in a console application. But I get the error message " The name 'Clipboard' does not exist in the current content". I searched the other questions about it and added `[STAThread]` but the problem is not being solved.

```
namespace Get_Text_Console_App
{

    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {
                string text = Clipboard.GetText();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to reference a namespace:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I tried this before. But I think I had to right click on Solution Explorer -> Add -> Reference -> System.Windows.Forms before adding the line to my code. I wonder if so but now it is working :)
...always hard in the beginning. Every little step goes sooooo slowly.

Comment: 1 second between our answers - very nice!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to `PresentationCore.dll` and put a `using System.Windows` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Is this project a WinForms project? From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Namespace: System.Windows.Forms

If this isn't, then you cannot use that class without referencing `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

In your csproj file, make sure you:

- Include `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` in the property group
- Append -windows to your [target framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks), for example `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`

I was looking for a reason as to why I could reference the System.Windows namespace yet still not access the Clipboard class. Turns out it's a part of WPF so you need to make sure your project is configured to use it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop

Comment: I was missing the `UseWPF` element in the csproj, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to `System.Windows.dll` (for WPF version) or `System.Windows.Forms.dll` (for winforms version) and make sure you import the namespace with a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just like some of the other answers, please make sure that you have a reference to the forms namespace by including it in your using space (since you're not using winforms and doing it from a console application):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Then also make sure in your references (as mentioned by Nick Bull) that `PresentationCore.dll` is included.

Then the last bit, I don't think that piece of code would work 100%, it's true that you need a STA thread, but the best execution I've made so far is:

```
static string GetClipText() {
  string res = string.Empty;
  Thread staThread = new Thread(x => {
     try {
         res = Clipboard.GetText();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)  {
        res = ex.Message;            
     }});
  staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  staThread.Start();
  staThread.Join();
  return res;
}
```

Then just call the new method in your code as such:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   if (Clipboard.ContainsText()) {
            string text = Clipboard.GetClipText();
   }
}
```